# Android animation happening after updates displayed

Tags: android, animation

So, I finally got my Animation sorted out (thanks to all that helped!).
However, I still have the problem that the animation is only displayed AFTER the other updates to the layout are.

What I am doing is dealing out a card to a user.
The animation shows the card sliding across the table.
However, the animation itself shows after the updates to the player's hand and the cards on the table are shown.

I tried making the update a separate thread and waiting on it but then I can't update the UI directly from there.
Sending a message to the UI thread doesn't help because the separate thread then ends after sending the message and I am back where I started.

I guess I am probably doing something wrong or missing something simple.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it sorted out.

I built my own animation class which implements AnimationListener.
I then use onAnimationEnd to make the changes in the so that they happen after the animation.